# Element-UI how to set default filter value in column filters

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

Element-ui version 2.1.0

```
<el-table-column
  prop="tag"
  label="Tag"
  width="100"
  :filters="[{ text: 'Home', value: 'Home' }, { text: 'Office', value: 'Office' }]"></el-table-column>
```

I want to set `Office` to default at first. I can't find any help in document.

Answer (score 4):

```
<el-table-column
  prop="tag"
  label="Tag"
  width="100"
  :filters="[{ text: 'Home', value: 'Home' }, { text: 'Office', value: 'Office' }]"
  :filtered-value="['Office']"
></el-table-column>
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, instead try adding some information explaining why your code helps solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 3):

I made a little hack function to force the table to apply a filter.

```
setDefaultFilter(colProp, filteredValue) {
  if (!this.$refs.tableRef) {
    throw new Error('Table should have a ref named tableRef.');
  }

  const typeColumn = this.$refs.tableRef.columns.find(col => col.property === colProp);

  typeColumn.filteredValue = filteredValue;

  this.$refs.tableRef.store.commit('filterChange', {
    column: typeColumn,
    values: filteredValue,
  });
  this.$refs.tableRef.store.updateAllSelected();
}
```

I used it in `mounted()` function like this:

```
const filteredValue = ['Private', 'Public'];

this.setDefaultFilter('type', filteredValue);
```

Comment: Hi there Sina. I applied this method and it works, but not completely. The problem is that the checkboxes are not being checked. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @ThibaultV sorry, I haven't touched vuejs in almost a year and I don't remember this quietly. I hope you can find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question but the way I solved it was by binding a data property:

```
data() {
  return {
    checkedFilters: [],
  };
},
```

to the :filtered-value table-column attribute.

```
<el-table-column
  column-key="states"
  label="State"
  :filters="stateFilters"
  :filter-method="filterState"
  :filtered-value="checkedFilters"
  v-if="isDisplayed('State')"
>
</el-table-column>
```